# securing twilio fax mediaUrl

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, fax

I am using Twilio programmable Fax api to send fax messages from my application.
I am not facing any issue while sending faxes when I provide a public url with out any authentication as mediaUrl for sending the fax. **But when I pass a url secured with basic authentication as the mediaUrl for the send fax api, the fax sending is getting failed.**

```
"status": "failed",
```

I have debugged the code on the server on which the mediaUrl accesses, and could find that Twilio is not at all sending a request with "Authorization" header.

> As per Twilio documentation,
>
> ```
> You may provide a username and password via the following URL format.
> ```
>
> https://username:password@www.myserver.com/my_secure_document
>
> Twilio will authenticate to your web server using the provided
>   username and password and will remain logged in for the duration of
>   the call. We highly recommend that you use HTTP Authentication in
>   conjunction with encryption. For more information on Basic and Digest
>   Authentication, refer to your web server documentation.
>
> If you specify a password-protected URL, Twilio will first send a
>   request with no Authorization header. After your server responds with
>   a 401 Unauthorized status code, a WWW-Authenticate header and a realm
>   in the response, Twilio will make the same request with an
>   Authorization header

I am giving the mediaUrl in the same format as required by Twilio. But the fax is getting response as failed. Kindly provide your valuable suggestions to help me resolve the issue.

My server is sending the 401 response as given below when Twilio accesses the mediaUrl without Authorization header,

Http response header for 401

```
  Status Code: 401 Unauthorized
    Content-Length: 34
    Content-Type: application/xml
    Date: Wed, 30 Aug 2017 12:38:41 GMT
    Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
    WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"
```

Response body

```
<message>Invalid credentials</message>
```

Comment: Is you server sending back a well formed 401 response when the authentication is not send?

Comment: Yes I am sending a well formed 401 response. Updated the 401 response on the question. Please check.

Comment: Seems ok. In your access logs, can you see Twilio attempting to retrieve your media with a second request containing the authorization header?

Comment: In the access log, I can see the first request from Twilio , for which my server returns a 401 response. After that, there is no subsequent request from Twilio and upon checking the fax details, getting the status of fax as failed. The same password protected mediaUrl when modified to serve TwiML for a webhook in Twilio, is accessed by Twilio first without Authorization header and then subsequently with an Authorization header and works fine.

Comment: It sounds like it could potentially be a bug on their end then. I would contact their support https://www.twilio.com/help/contact

Comment: Hey syed, I've updated my answer, but this has now been implemented so you should be able to use basic auth with files for Fax now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**

Good news! Media URLs in [Twilio Programmable Fax](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/fax) now support basic authentication. This has been implemented and deployed, so this should no longer be an issue.

**Original answer**

Twilio developer evangelist here.

After some internal investigation I've found out that this is a known issue.

It was in fact raised by your support ticket that you sent in. Good news is that since this is known it will be getting some attention and the team will contact you once it is sorted.

Comment: Thanks @philnash for the follow up.

Comment: Hi @philnash,

Is there any documentation on how to secure the media resource and how to secure the mediaUrl / granting Twillio permission?  A short write up / tutorial would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @TianhuiLi you can secure the media resource with HTTP Basic Authentication. How you achieve that depends on your web server or where you are serving the media from.

Answer (score 0):

To answer this question differently, I'm just using [Signed URLs on Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls), which provide a long token that grants temporary access for a specific file.  You can set this to grant access for 10 minutes, which should be more than enough time.

AWS appears to offer a [similar solution](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/presign.html).